# Look for Promise bluebird code review for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

When and where need to use [`new Promise(Function<Function resolve, Function reject> resolver) -> Promise`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise)

## My Sample code:

userInfo.js

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var winston = require('winston');
var _ = require('lodash');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));

exports.getWeather = function (data) {
    var cityName = data.userProfile.city;
    return request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/Weather/byCity?city=" + cityName).spread(function (res, body) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body).data;
        return _.merge(data, result);
    });
};

exports.getUserProfile = function (userId) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/UserProfile/getUserProfile?id=" + userId).spread(function (res, body) {
            var result = JSON.parse(body).data;
            resolve(result);
        });
    })

};

exports.getEvents = function (data) {
    var cityName = data.userProfile.city;
    return request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/Events/byCity?city=" + cityName).spread(function (res, body) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body).data;
        return _.merge(data, result);
    });
};

exports.getFashion = function (data) {
    var gender = data.userProfile.gender;
    return request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/Fashion/byGender?gender=" + gender).spread(function (res, body) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body).data;
        return _.merge(data, result);
    });
};

exports.displayDetail = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

Above code I try call in 2 way in promise

getUserProfile.js

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
    module.exports = function(){
       return userInfo.getUserProfile(3)
                    .then(userInfo.getFashion)
                    .then(userInfo.getEvents)
                    .then(userInfo.getWeather)
                    .then(userInfo.displayDetail)
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        console.log('Error:');
                        console.error(e.stack)
                    })
                    .finally(function () {
                        console.log('done');
                    });

    }
```

2nd way:

getUserInformation.js

```
var userInfo = require('./userInfo');
     module.exports = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

             resolve(3);
        })
            .then(userInfo.getUserProfile)
                .then(userInfo.getFashion)
                .then(userInfo.getEvents)
                .then(userInfo.getWeather)
                .then(userInfo.displayDetail)
                .catch(function (e) {
                    console.log('Error:');
                    console.error(e.stack)
                })
                .finally(function () {
                    console.log('done');
                });
    };
```

getDetails.js

```
var userInfo = require('./getUserInformation');
    userInfo()
    .then(function(){
            console.log('getDetails done')
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log('Error:');
            console.error(e.stack)
        })
        .finally(function () {
            console.log('done');
        });
```

please let me know what the difference and is there any issues by using these way?

Comment: difference between what? what kind of issues?

Comment: i am looking for code review.. which approach is right?

Comment: Both are, assuming the other approach is to use node.js style callbacks.

Comment: but creating dummy new Promise and then doing chaining is right? right what happening in background.. and is there any performance issue is there?

Comment: Are you seeing a performance issue?

Comment: I see no reason for you to do what was mentioned in `2nd way`. Why would that even be a consideration. To be clear, though, it isn't **wrong**, it's just not necessary.

Comment: what wrong in 2nd way event i am getting same output. if you explain in detail that will very helpful for me

Comment: Like I said, it isn't **wrong**, it's just not necessary. Having the dummy promise is no different from not having it other than it's extra.

Comment: thanks Kevin. really where we need to use new promise?

Comment: When you're working with something that doesn't implement the promise api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85473/discussion-between-elankeeran-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> exports.getUserProfile = function (userId) {
>     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
>         request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/UserProfile/getUserProfile?id=" + userId).spread(function (res, body) {
>             var result = JSON.parse(body).data;
>             resolve(result);
>         });
>     })
> };
> ```

[Please don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). Just `return` from the callback, and return the promise created by `then`, like you have done it in your other three methods.

> ```
> return userInfo.getUserProfile(3)
> .then(…)
> ```
>
> vs.
>
> ```
> return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
>     resolve(3);
> })
> .then(userInfo.getUserProfile)
> .then(…)
> ```

Well, the first one is much more readable and concise. They're pretty much equivalent except for the case that `getUserProfile` does throw synchronously, which it shouldn't anyway. Also in the first case `getUserProfile` is invoked as a method *on* `userInfo`, while in the second case it's just a callback function, the `this` in the calls will be different.

The second pattern can be tremendously simplified though by using `Promise.resolve` instead of the `new Promise` constructor:

```
return Promise.resolve(3)
.then(userInfo.getUserProfile)
.then(…)
```

This is totally fine, and aligns better with the rest of the chain. Speaking of which, …

> ```
> .then(userInfo.getFashion)
> .then(userInfo.getEvents)
> .then(userInfo.getWeather)
> ```
>
> where each of the functions returns a promise that resolves with
>   additional data merged into its argument

is not exactly the best way to solve this. Yes, it ensures that these three functions are called after each other, and [is an acceptable pattern for that case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250693/1048572). However, in your case you're mixing the `request` calls to the API with that argument-extraction and result-merging in the same function; which by the separation of concerns you shouldn't. Rather make the functions pure

```
exports.… = function (arg) {
    return request("http://0.0.0.0:3003/api/…?…=" + arg).spread(function (res, body) {
        return JSON.parse(body).data;
    });
};
```

And now you can combine them separately - and not only in sequence, but also in parallel:

```
userInfo.getUserProfile(3)
.then(function(data) {
    var p = data.userProfile;
    return Promise.prop({
         userProfile: 0,
         fashion: userInfo.getFashion(p.gender), // `\
         events: userInfo.getEvents(p.city),     //   }=> execute requests in parallel
         weather: userInfo.getWeather(p.city)    // ./
    });
})
.then(userInfo.displayDetail)
.catch(function (e) {
     console.error('Error:', e.stack)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way is much more readable, and there's no benefit to starting the chain with a promise that returns a constant as in your second way.

They both do effectively the same thing, with one caveat: In your second example (Starting the chain with a Promise), the `getUserProfile` call will be run on the next tick (Similar to if you'd thrown it in a setTimeout 0) rather than atomically.